# Opening .msg file(Outlook item file) in android programmatically

Tags: android, outlook

I am trying to open a .MSG file through my application. I tried with setting the MIMETYPE as `vnd.ms-outlook`, still i couldn't able to open up the .MSG file as i expected, then i tried with attaching the same .MSG in email and opened in my device. It opened like a charm.

So my question is , How can i open up the .MSG file in android programmatically within the application.

Tried with following methods,

Method 1 : Setting the MIMETYPE manually

```
mimetype = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";
```

Method 2 : Fetching the MIMETYPE through `MimeTypeMap`

```
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension); // extension is msg
```

Opening the .MSG file through another installed application

```
Log.i(TAG, "Extension :" + extension + "\n" + "MIME :" + mimetype); // Prints msg for extension and mimetype = application/vnd.ms-outlook for method 1 and null when i use method 2
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
startActivity(intent);
```

The mimetype in Method 2 results null and the mimetype set explicitly too doesn't work.

Could anybody share their thoughts on solving this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean my "open"? are you trying to parse it in your app or send it to another app?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to open it through another application that support opening up .MSG files say for example , office suite.

Comment: When i tried the same .MSG file attached in my email and opened in my device through Office suite. It got opened. The same way i trying to open.

Comment: you may want to post your code for actually "opening" the file. you have posted stuff about the mimetype but nothing about the actual opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an intent to open the file with another app. Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(msgURI, mimeTypeString);
startActivity(i);
```

That should allow any app that has registered the MSG's data type in its manifest to open it.

Comment: This is the way , i too have used. Still it doesn't opens up with the installed application. Throws ActivityNotFoundException.

Comment: FYI,I have updated the code (Included the code for actually "opening" the file)

Comment: i would try to find an app that lets you view the manifest for another app. Here's one that works well enough: [PackageExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.andr.pkgexp&hl=en). Find the Office Suite and look what it accepts. That should give you a good idea what you need to put for the data type of your intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try with it and post my comments. Thanks once again pal.

Comment: Still i couldn't able to open it.

Comment: I will brief my question,I am working on a file manager kind of application,in which i need to open an .MSG file through a supportable installed application in the device.I came to know that i can able to open the .MSG file through the application called "Office Suite".Though,it is installed on my device,When i tried to open it through this application,Its not getting opened(throws ActivityNotFoundException).but,When i open the same file(.MSG) which is attached in the email,"Office Suite" opens that file. I hope, I have conveyed my query at the best.Please let me know your valuable suggestions

Comment: i understand the question. you need to find out what "Office Suite" accepts as intent data types and build your intent based off that. the other option would be to find the activity that opens it and explicitly call it. that's bad because not everyone has that app, and users might want to use a different one.

Comment: @toadzky have you find any solution, i am in the same situation, if any one know please post code here

Comment: There isn't another solution. Android intents are a registry where apps tell the system what they support. You need to know what apps will accept to get them to show up as an option when selecting an app